# Active DB queries in Wordpress?

Tags: mysql, wpdb

I just make some researches regarding to wordpress DB queries and I just wonder if I miss something

a normal `SELECT` query for example in Codeigniter with active records would look like if I assume I init my DB instance in both of the cases inside of a Class as `$this->db`

```
$data = $this->db->get('wp_mytable');
$data->result();
```

**Wordpress way**

```
$data = $this->db->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_mytable');
```

and if I would use a condition than would look like

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('wp_mytable');
$this->db->where('id', 1);
$this->db->result();
```

I find this handy if I would use more than one `WHERE` as array

but I do not see this kind of query types in wordpress [wiki](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) or I do not search in the right place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wpdb` doesn't include such kind of API, mostly since it descended from ezSQL which didn't either (as far as I remember).

While there are *some* helpers for insert/update stuff, most of query abstraction happens in [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) since that's where bulk of complicated querying is typically going on.

Comment: anyway, maybe wordpress needs a better DB class if we compare with laravel or codeigniter